# Finding the Pantone colors used in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, logo, pantone

I have a logo that is getting put on to golf shirts and the company has asked for a list of the pantone colors. Is there a way to get a list of all the colors through illustrator?

Answer (score 3):

- Select the artwork
- Click the `New Color Group` icon at the bottom of the **Swatches Panel** -- [image]
- Tick the `Selected Artwork` option
  [image]
- Swatches will then be listed in the **Swatch Panel** as a group
  [image]

You may need to use the **Swatch Panel Menu** and choose `Large List View` or `Small List View`

If you are sending a PDF, you can also use Acrobat to simply list the spot colors in the file.